# Graphs on the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Describe the set of complex numbers
>
> a) $Im(\frac1{z})<-1/2$
>
> b) $Re(z^2)<1$
>
> c)$\bigg|\frac{z+1}{z-1} \bigg|<1$
>
> on the complex plane.

For A), B), C), I understand the question, but the combination of complex numbers is hindering me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will solve a) for you, the rest you should try on your own:

Ok so here we go:

a) $\Im(\frac{1}{z})<-\frac{1}{2}$

Solution:

Note that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ can be re-written as a function of $(x,y)$ as follows:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}=\frac{\bar{z}}{z\bar{z}}=\frac{\bar{z}}{|z|^2}$$

Since $z=x+iy$, we get that:

$$f(z)=f(x+iy)=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}-i\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} $$

Thus,

$$\Im{f(z)}=-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} $$

So the original inequality translates to:

$$-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} < -\frac{1}{2} \implies \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} > \frac{1}{2} \implies 2y > x^2+y^2$$

Carrying on with the inequality, this is:

$$ x^2+y^2 <2y \implies x^2+y^2-2y<0 \implies x^2+(y-1)^2<1 $$

The last line follows by completing the square. The region in the complex plane (i.e. in $(x,y)$) is described as the interior of a circle with radius 1 and center $(0,1)$. Of course, $(0,1)$ is the complex number $z=i$.

Hints for the rest:

b) $f(z)=z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$, so $\Re{f(z)}$ is...

c) Square both sides and use the property that $z\bar{z}=|z|^2$